# Embedding Microsoft Power BI into Liferay

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, liferay-ide, powerbi

I am currently doing a computer science degree. As part of my industry project for my university, I am developing a BI solution for a client. Having gone though the project I'd like to develop it using Liferay. Does anyone know whether it is possible to embed Microsoft Power BI into Liferay.
The ideal scenario is that the client logs in to a Liferay portal and views power bi dashboards on the portal. Can this be done, is it possible? If so how can this be achieved?
If not what are the alternatives?

I would appreciate your help.

By the way I have to use power bi as part of the project

Answer (score 0):

Well, yes, of course it's possible. What do you need to do? *It depends*. You can use an iframe immediately or rewrite the reports UI in a portlet. You can even write the whole administrative UI as a portlet. These options were all in increasing amounts of effort you'll have to put into it (and frankly, rewriting *all* of the UI would be ridiculous, I don't expect you to do this).

You might want to check

- Single Sign On for Liferay and BI
- Options for BI to be integrated in any other applications, its API (might be: iframe, distinct media - e.g. images, JSON representations of reports etc)
- The amount of seamless integration you need - e.g. is an extra click accepted? How many resources (time) do you have to implement the integration?

This was meant to be a comment, but it's too long for that.

Comment: What you also could consider (If you haven't yet decided on MBI) usin Talend as the BI solution. As it is completely Java-based, an integration could be a little easier. Also there is already a portlet in the marketplace which utilizes Talend, and where you can upload Task and execute then.

Answer (score 0):

PowerBI.com, Power BI for Office 365, or some of the on premises offers like Power View in SharePoint 2013?

For www.powerbi.com, embedding dashboards is something we're looking at. You can vote for it at the link below to keep updated when it is available.
https://support.powerbi.com/forums/265200-power-bi/suggestions/6769940-embed-visualizations-in-an-external-webpage

For Power BI for Office 365, you can embed excel workbooks that contain Power View sheets in web pages, though if you're building an applications this may not be ideal.

Let us know more of the details you're looking for.

Appreciate your using Power BI.

-Lukasz

http://dev.powerbi.com

http://blogs.msdn.com/powerbidev

Comment: Appreciate your input Lukasz. You mention that embedding excel workbooks containing power view sheets in web view is not ideal. Could you please elaborate of why this is not suitable? Thanks